# How to quickly type "->" in Netbeans for PHP

Tags: php, autocomplete, netbeans

Almost C++ IDE know when they should turn the "." to "->", but with some off my PHP IDE they don't.
For example:

```
$f = new Foo;
$f. // will not turn to $f->
```

Is there any trick for do that in Netbeans?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this could be done easily in netbeans when developing your PHP 
To Type "->" quickly you can use a macro recording. for example

> Go to Edit and click star Macro Recording
>   Then type in -> and then click stop stop Macro Recording

Then You will get a dialog box type in the Name for the macro and then click

> set shortcut and assign a easy keyboard shortcut eg- Alt + x

After that click ok and then onwards when you press alt + x you will get -> on screen.